# UWP App caching entire page along with data

Tags: c#, performance, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a Windows 10 UWP application (MVVM, Caliburn) and have enabled caching to reduce load on memory,

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

The problem with this is that it is even caching the data that is plugging in from the ViewModel, for instance, a grid or bar chart is not reflecting the changes from the database and only showing the state they are cached in.

Any suggestions on how I can enable the caching and get refreshed data everytime a page opens?

Answer (score 2):

Are you overriding the `OnNavigatedTo` method? This will get calles every time the page is navigated to, and you can refresh the data then.

Comment: Data is refreshed on ViewModel level, and OnNavigatedTo event is in the cs file of the view. Not sure how I can update data from this event.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bindings.Update(); to manually refresh the x:Bind expressions on the specific view and as Peter Torr said you should call it in the OnNavigatedTo method override.

Comment: Resolved it by loading the data in OnActivate (I'm using Caliburn) method in my ViewModel. Thanks (: